# Final variable may already have been assigned

Tags: java, eclipse

I am writing a program that has two final variables that I wish to use, I need these to be set at the time that I actually run the class because they are likely to be different each instance.

I have the initialization the same as any other class variable I wish to use where I initialize a name and type but not a value.

```
   public final String filename, filepath;
```

In the Constructor I set the values as follows

```
 public myClass(String value) {
     this.filename = value;
     this.filepath = anotherPartOfValue;
  }
```

When I do this, I get a warning that "The final field [x] may have already been assigned"

Is there a way to avoid this warning and still keep the final state and set the value in the constructor?

I am using eclipse btw.

---

Edit:

This is the exact code that gives me the error

```
import java.io.*;

public class Dirt {

private String[] tables;
private int numTables;
private final String filename, filepath;

public Dirt(String file) {
    this.tables = new String[0];
    this.numTables = 0;

    for (int i = file.length(); i < 0; i--) {
        if (file.charAt(i) == '/') {
            this.filename = file.substring(i);
            this.filepath = file.substring(1, i-1);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't get that warning with your code as posted. Have you shown us everything relevant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning to the final variables in a loop. There's nothing to prevent the loop from looping more than once and the `if` condition being satisfied more than once. (What happens if there are two '/' characters in `file`? Or none?)

One way around this is to use temporary String variables in the constructor and then assign them to `filename` and `filepath` at the end:

```
public Dirt(String file) {
    this.tables = new String[0];
    this.numTables = 0;
    String name = null;
    String path = null;

    for (int i = file.length(); i < 0; i--) {
        if (file.charAt(i) == '/') {
            name = file.substring(i);
            path = file.substring(1, i-1);
            // need a break here?
        }
    }
    this.filename = name;
    this.filepath = path;
}
```

It's ugly, but it's a straightforward way to know for sure that `filename` and `filepath` will definitely be assigned and definitely be assigned only once.

Comment: This is exactly what I had just figured out. feeling a little dumb right now :P

Comment: Good to know. By the way, you might consider using the String method `lastIndexOf(int c)` in place of your loop. :)

Comment: I can't do that (I think) because I do not know where to break the String except as 'at the last '/' character.

Comment: `file.lastIndexOf('/')` will give you the index of the **last** '/' character in `file` (or -1 if there isn't one). Isn't that exactly what your loop is doing?

Answer (score 2):

Completely compileable and runnable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo f = new Foo("abc");
    System.out.println(f.filename);
    System.out.println(f.filepath);
}

static class Foo {
    public final String filename, filepath;
    public Foo(String value) {
        this.filename = value;
        this.filepath = value.substring(1);
    }
}
```

And the "warning" you mention isn't just a warning. It's an error. But it's not coming from here.

**Edit:** Your newly posted code has the assignments in a loop. By definition, statements in a loop can execute multiple times, and therefore you have the potential for assigning the final variables multiple times.

Comment: Figured it out now. My for loop had no break in it so it was possible that it could initialize multiple times, I put a break in and it takes away the error. Thanks for the brain jog.... :P

Comment: @Andy - Putting in a break should give you a different error -- that the variables may not receive an assignment at all.

Comment: @Ted I got that, but using temporary variables to get to the values and assigning at the end gets past it.